# How to fetch continent of the user located in?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I want to know the continent name in which the user is located.  Can i get it from regional setting or have to use some service to fetch continent from current lat/lng?  If service, which one will be appropriate to fetch continent details?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this can be done like this

For Example I have made a code to get the timezone.

```
NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",localTime);
```

I am getting an output as follows - **current local timezone is Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800**

So I got the whole timezone. What I do now in this is add this in an `NSString`. Then use the property of the `NSString` class `componentsSeparatedByString` to get the "/" operator.

The full code is as follows :-

```
    NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",localTime);
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",localTime];
    NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *strHi = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",strHi);
```

According to this code you would get the value of **strHi** as **Asia**.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Check out this utility: https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones.

It gets NSTimeZone from CLLocation.